# install Python modules in Rstudio

Tags: python, r, module, reticulate

I am trying to run python 3.8 in Rstudio using mac system. However, I am confused about installing modules using reticulate. When I install `scipy` using `py_install("scipy")`, I can install it successfully. However, when I test its availability, I got `FALSE` output, and therefore, I cannot import `scipy` module.

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3")
py_available() # TRUE
py_install("scipy") # installed sucessfully
py_module_available("scipy") # FALSE
```

If i use `sudo pip install scipy` in R `terminal`, I can successfully install it and import it. Can somebody explain why i cannot install Python module using `py_install`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you read the vigentte of py_install, the command "Install Python packages into a virtual environment or Conda environment". So you are always installing into an environment which is separate from your actual python installation (in either conda or /usr/local/bin)

Comment: You can however use the module scipy after you use py_install

Comment: @StupidWolf， Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I cannot import the module if i use py_install.

Comment: I see. Ok I have scipy installed, but lets say we do something like py_install("pygame"); then pygame <- import_from_path("pygame",path='~/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')

Comment: This should work. You check out the message you get when the package is installed  using py_install. Your default path might be different from mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this "answer" works for people arriving here based on OP title; works also in jupyter

```
import os
os.system("pip3 install pandas")
```

Or:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('pip3 install pytesseract'.split())
```

or:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['pip3', 'install', "pandas"])
```